# Erro de compilação com Pycharm: não acha bibliotecas do python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

Sistema Operacional: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bits
Python 3.6 instalado via apt-get

Ao compilar um programa no terminal usando:

```
python3.6 programa.py
```

Nenhum erro é apresentado.

Ao rodar o mesmo programa com a IDE pycharm ou Wing Python, com python3.6, recebo erros de bibliotecas (por exemplo, numpy, pycuda) nao encontrados.

O código executado:

```
#https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/tutorial.html

import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule


import numpy
a = numpy.random.randn(4,4)


a = a.astype(numpy.float32)

a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)

cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu, a)


mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void doublify(float *a)
  {
    int idx = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y*4;
    a[idx] *= 2;
  }
  """)
```

Erro (apenas na IDE, rodando do terminal não há erro):

```
pytools.prefork.ExecError: error invoking 'nvcc --version': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvcc'
```

Dúvida: como fazer para as IDEs usaram a mesma instalação do python3.6 que funciona ao chamar no terminar? Como descobrir qual é esta instalação que está com todas as bibliotecas instaladas?

PS: Descobri o problema. So nao sei como resolver. As IDEs Python não estao enxergando as variáveis de ambiente e não sei como setá-las!

Answer (score -1):

**Modificando o interpretador no PyCharm**

Acesse a opção Settings (File >> Settings),
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No menu lateral achar a opção Project e dentro dela Project Interpreter, na tela a direita selecionar o interpretador desejado.

Comment: o problema é que nenhum funcionou...

Comment: eu tentei isso mas não consegui encontrar um "caminho do python" que funcionava.... Como achar o mesmo caminho que o python3 que usei no terminal?

Comment: **1) Abra o Terminal do Ubuntu, com CRTL + T**

2) No terminal digite:

which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

3) Com o comando acima ele te da caminho de qualquer arquivo/executavel

Comment: Descobri o problema. So nao sei como resolver. As IDEs Python não estao enxergando as variáveis de ambiente e não sei como setá-las!

Comment: No ubuntu não precisa fazer isso, por vc poe ter varias versões do python instaladas. Vc só precisa setar na configuração da IDE ou do EDITOR, no caso Pycharm! Como mostrei acima.

Comment: **Acrescente a linhas a seguir no final do arquivo .bashrc que está no seu diretório home:**   

PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin/python3  </br>

export PYTHONPATH

Comment: which python3
/usr/bin/python3
esta é a saida

Comment: Editei a pergunta. O erro persiste!

Comment: Vc fez o que foi proposto, acrescentou a variável de ambiente do python no final no arquivo .bashrc que esta no seu home? Ao inves de usar PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin/python3 usa o que esta configurando na sua maquina: PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python3 e na linha de baixo digita: export PYTHONPATH. Fecha o arquivo .bashrc, no terminal digita: source .bashrc

Comment: vou verificar de novo e retorno aqui!

Comment: Mesma coisa: pytools.prefork.ExecError: error invoking 'nvcc --version': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvcc'

Comment: Fiz tudo como vc falou! A compilacao funciona apenas do terminal. NO pyacharm, recebo o erro acima!

Comment: Eu já consertei isso uma vez. Tinha haver com o modo como o Ubuntu armazena uma variável $ PATH separada para o sudo em oposição ao usuário comum. Uma vez que eu fiz as mudanças necessárias em /etc/environment para adicionar o caminho do nvcc /usr/local/cuda-8, tudo ficou bem.

Comment: entao basta editar o arquivo  /etc/environment e adicionar  /usr/local/cuda-9.2    Seria isso? Vou testar

Comment: Eu descobri que tudo funciona se eu rodar a IDE como root... Se rodar com meu usuario comum, dá o erro!

Comment: então muda as permissões do diretório para usuário poder usar!